# Looking for a Parallel Coordinates chart for GWT

Tags: java, gwt, charts, data-visualization

Looking for [Parallel Coordinates chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_coordinates) for GWT

I need to show something like the following image. Interactive is a plus but is not mandatory and size of data set is not big.

[image: sample taken from wikipedia]

I seen the Protovis. It has [this car sample](http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/ex/cars.html) that is just amazing but I do not know how to wrap it up and use from GWT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check out the [protovis-GWT](http://code.google.com/p/choosel/wiki/ProtovisGWT) wrapper. If the specific chart is not supported by the GWT wrapper you can also try to use protovis directly via JSNI.

There is also a custom google chart for parallel coordinates which you can find [here](http://parallel-coordinates.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/documentation/documentation.html). You could use that in combination with the gwt visualization api.

Comment: yes I aware of that. How to make it work with GWT...  protovis-GWT wrapping does not look that simple at all. and parallel-coordinates.googlecode.com has same problem.

Comment: For parallel-coordinates.googlecode.com you have to create a Visualization Wrapper (as an example you can look at the ColumnChart wrapper). For Protovis you have to convert the protovis code to protovis-GWT wrapper code. 
You can check the Arc Graph as an example. If you check the GWT and the protovis code it's almost identical:
http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/ex/arc.html
http://code.google.com/p/choosel/source/browse/trunk/org.thechiselgroup.choosel.protovis/examples/org/thechiselgroup/choosel/protovis/client/ArcDiagramExample.java
http://web.uvic.ca/~lgrammel/blog/protovis-gwt/index.html

Comment: can somebody provide the GWT wrapper?